# IE11 FormData AJAX Post with File hangs after 401

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, iis-7.5, internet-explorer-11

In IE11, I'm using ajax to post a FormData element to a Windows Authenticated endpoint (IIS7.5 NTLM). If the FormData element only contains text fields, everything works great -- the initial request results in a 401 and the payload gets delivered in the subsequent request that carries the credentials/payload.

However, this does *not* work if there is a File input in the FormData object.  If there is a file in the FormData object, IE11 will send the request, get the 401, and then not send the subsequent request at all.  (note -- it *does* work in FF/Chrome)

Code:

```
// This works
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append("CaseId", 1188);
fd.append("PhaseId", 6);

// Adding this element to the FD makes IE11 hang
// but still works in FF & Chrome
fd.append("MyFile", document.getElementById("MyFileInput").files[0]);

$.ajax({
  url  : "myEndpoint.ashx",
  type : "POST",
  data : fd,
  contentType : false, // do not to adjust content-type
  processData : false, // do not to convert raw data to string
  success     : function(data){
    console.log("Hooray!");
  },
  error : function(xhr){
    console.log("Boo");
  }
});
```

I have examined the request headers with/without the file input in Fiddler and the 401 request/responses are identical in every way.

Here is the Working Request (no file input). The subsequent request that follows this one includes credentials and results in a 200

```
POST http://example.com/myEndpoint.ashx HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7df11b0308d6
Referer: http://example.com/IE11FormDataTest.html
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: example.com
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=mqa12rwnmxerfoz3csx0wohk
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==
Content-Length: 0
```

And Here is the request that does NOT work (file input included in FormData object). When this returns, IE11 fails to issue a subsequent, authenticated request. In fact, the title of the tab just says "Waiting for mysite.com...":

```
POST http://example.com/myEndpoint.ashx HTTP/1.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7df2c7308d6
Referer: http://example.com/IE11FormDataTest.html
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: example.com
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=mqa12rwnmxerfoz3csx0wohk
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==
Content-Length: 0
```

Does anybody see anything that I could be missing or have any suggestions for tests I could run/create?  I have tried the same thing with a raw XMLHttpRequest, but the result was the same.

Comment: Can you say what version IE you have ?
I have the same issue on 11.0.9600.17501.

Comment: @DAiMor - I'm on the same version. 11.0.9600.17501

Comment: @DAiMor - Looks like we're not alone. https://twitter.com/ericlaw/status/448936646633725952

Comment: and on server 2008 R2 version 11.0.9600.16428. It looks like MS have solution for this issue http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2980019 in IE 10, But it doesn't work for our IE.

Comment: And it doesn't work on Windows 10 and IE 11.0.9841.0

Comment: I solved it with form in IFrame, and by userAgent for IE11, I show some window for choosing file.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem and I still have no idea how to solve it. Anybody had more chance ?

Comment: @JulienD. We weren't able to resolve it. We had to create another application that used token based security instead of windows auth and posting to that from our app instead. Sucks but seems to be the only way. I wonder if the new Edge browser has resolved this problem...

Comment: @Mr.JavaScript Thank you for your answer. Edge doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with File Data appended at the last. This was resolved if I append one more key value pair to the form data.

This link pointed me in the right direction
https://blog.yorkxin.org/posts/2014/02/06/ajax-with-formdata-is-broken-on-ie10-ie11/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  We tried that method and it still failed under NTLM/Windows Auth.  To check, we disabled Windows auth and it started working, so we know its definitely a bug in IE when using Windows Auth :(

Answer (score -2):

This is no a javascript problem. You should look at the server-side code.

For file upload, I had to use FormData. When I used XMLHttpRequest, a syntax error occurred IE11 while it worked fine on Chrome and Firefox.
When I changed it to ajax call, it started working correctly.

But another problem occurred. The string value I sent was url-encoded and I wasn't getting the url parameters correctly.

Comment: You might want to provide some examples from your solution that are relevant to the js in the question to improve your answer.

Comment: @Alex: Hmm...I'm not sure about that.  The fact that it works with any browser at all negates the possiblity of it being a server-side problem. We've experimented extensively with async requests from a variety of libraries, including raw XmlHttpRequests, and the problem persists. It is definitely an issue with IE11.  There's an official bug filed with Microsoft   (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2980019), for which their prescribed fix does not work.  See the comments in the op for more info.